# Illustrator: Round stroke on polygon corners

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I'm using the polygon tool in Illustrator to create polygons. When I use Effect-Stylize-round corners, it rounds the fill of the polygon, but does not round the outline. How can I round the outline as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternate workflow option:

- create a polygon
- select it by clicking inside the polygon with the white arrow tool
- adjust the corner widgets (View> Show Corner Widget) to your liking by click/ dragging them in or out

You can always re-adjust the corner radius by re-selecting the shape and changing the corner widget position or you can numerically set the corner radius in the Transform Panel (Window> Transform).

Effects can be easily modified in the Appearance Panel but usually will need to be expanded which separates the fill from the stroke- I do not see a reason to work with an effect when what you are doing can be built right into the object without using an effect.

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you so much for adding this. How can I only select/move one corner?

Comment: With your polygon un-selected- click on an anchor point with the White Arrow tool. It will show just the corner widget for that corner and you can adjust it independently.

Answer (score 0):

Applying an Illustrator Effect acts as part of the object without permanently changing the object unless you expand the object. This makes the effect non-destructive, you can alter the effect later on if you want to.

Answer: Select the object, go to Object -> Expand Appearance.

From Adobe

> Once you apply an effect to an object, the effect appears in the
> Appearance panel. From the Appearance panel, you can edit the effect,
> move it, duplicate it, delete it, or save it as part of a graphic
> style. When you use an effect, you must expand the object before you
> can access the new points.

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/effects.html